# Can someone please explain how to calculate MNA (minimum number alive or minimum number known alive) in as many simple steps as possible?

Tags: statistics

I've read a bunch of literature on MNA and I can't understand how it differs from just summing up all unique captures over the course of the study. I've done 6 primary capture sessions, each with 3 secondary capture sessions, across 12 sites, and need to calculate MNA.

If MNA is the sum of unique individuals caught during the current session, and all unique individuals NOT caught during the current session but caught during previous AND subsequent sessions, wouldn't MNA be the same at every time, equaling just a sum of unique captures?